# store edited svg image with json

Tags: javascript, json, svg, colors, storage

i am currently developing an application that lets the user change the colours of different parts of an svg image of a dress, e.g they can choose a colour for the sleeves, the main body, the neckline etc. the user can also drag and drop shapes provided onto the dress for added design. what i want to do now is to store their edited design to a json file and when they log back in they can retrieve the design. Does anyone know how i go about doing this to make sure that the colours the user chose, along with their added shapes save to the positions they had clicked?

Comment: SVG itself is an XML document which you can parse and serialize. Take reference from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML and see if it helps. Otherwise if you insists for JSON only, then can convert XML (read SVG) to JSON, there are many solutions around but that depends on what library/framework are you using to build your application

Comment: i'm not very familiar with using svg images so i'm very new to this and dont understand much from that website you sent me. I'm using ASP.NET to hard code the svg paths and then call a js file that use colour functions and another js file that has the drag and drop function

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WebForms or MVC? Here is the 'sample' code. Do not use 'as is'.

The idea is to have a hidden texarea in form and before submit you serialize the svg to text and set it to texarea. You can then retrieve this svg-in-text-form at server side and save into database

```js
function serializeSVG(){
 var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
 var svg = document.getElementsById('svg1');
 var serializedSvg = oSerializer.serializeToString(svg);
 var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('<%= Page.Master.FindControl("myHiddenInput").ClientID %>');
 
 hiddenInput.value = serializedSvg;

return true;
 
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return serializeSVG();" >
<asp:HiddenField id="myHiddenInput" runat="server" />
...
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   viewBox="0 0 512 512"
   id="svg1"
   version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="gradFace">
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#FFDD00"/>
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#FFCC00"/>
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#FFAA00"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FD7409"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="gradEye">
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#FFF"/>
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#D6D6D6"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#525355"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <linearGradient id="gradIris" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="10%"  stop-color="#0A0A0A" />
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#777777" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="glow" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="1" />
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.5" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="gradSmile" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="50%"  stop-color="#734204" />
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#8A4E05" />
    </linearGradient>
    <g id="eye">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="84" fill="url(#gradEye)" />
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="28" fill="url(#gradIris)" stroke="#0A0A0A" />
    </g>
    <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" id="filterEye">
      <feMorphology
         radius="6"
         in="SourceGraphic"
         result="result0"
         id="feMorphology3099" />
      <feGaussianBlur
         in="result0"
         stdDeviation="5"
         result="result91"
         id="feGaussianBlur3101" />
      <feComposite
         operator="in"
         in="SourceGraphic"
         in2="result91"
         id="feComposite3103" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
    <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" fill="url(#gradFace)" />
    <path style="fill:url(#glow);opacity:0.9;filter:url(#filterEye)" d="m 464,155 c 0,67 -93,27 -208,27 -115,0 -207,41 -207,-27 0,-67 90,-143 205,-143 115,0 210,75 210,143 z" />
    
    <g id="eyesGlow" style="fill:#;filter:url(#filterEye)">
        <circle cx="142" cy="256" r="100" fill="#FFDD00" />
        <circle cx="370" cy="256" r="100" fill="#FFDD00" />
    </g>
    <g id="eyes">
        <use xlink:href="#eye" x="142" y="256" />
        <use xlink:href="#eye" x="370" y="256" />
    </g>
    
    <g>
        <rect style="fill:#FFDD00;" width="130" height="38" x="191" y="390" rx="6" ry="16" filter="url(#filterEye)" />
        <rect style="fill:url(#gradSmile);stroke:#734204" width="110" height="30" x="201" y="400" rx="15" ry="15" />
    </g>
    
    <g style="fill:url(#gradSmile);stroke:#734204" id="eyebbrows" y="0">
        <path d="m 311, 107 c 0, 0 6, -18 45, -18 44, 1 68, 35 68, 35 -8, 3 -37, -15 -48, -19 -26, -7 -65, 1 -65, 1 z" />
        <path d="m 201, 107 c 0, 0 -6, -18 -45, -18 -44, 1 -68, 35 -68, 35 8, 3 37, -15 48, -19 26, -7 65, 1 65, 1 z" />
    </g>
    
</svg>

<button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
...
</form>
```

Idea:

1. Add 'id' to your svg, so you can get identify/find in JavaScript
2. Add onsubmit method on form *< form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return serializeSVG();" >*
3. In function serializeSVG, set serialized svg to hidden input
4. Get the value at server side

I'm not very good with .NET so feel free to fix the code for your convenience

Answer (score 0):

i am using web forms. here is an example of one of my svg images i have included along with an example of the js file

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Dress7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
<path class="main-body" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M73.9,359.4c5,2,8.8-1.4,13-2.8c6.3-2.2,12.4-4.9,18.5-7.6c4.7-2.1,9.2-4.5,13.9-6.5c1.7-0.7,2.8-1.7,3.3-3.5
    c3.7-13.4,7.6-26.8,11.1-40.3c3.5-13.5,6.1-27.4,10.3-40.7c2.6-8.3,1.3-16.2,0.7-24.3c-0.6-8-1.4-16-2.4-24
    c-1.5-11.3-3.3-22.6-4.8-33.9c-1.1-7.7-1.9-15.4-2.9-23.1c-0.3-2.7-0.9-5.1-2.5-7.6c-2-3-2.9-6.7-4.1-10.1
    c-4.4-12.3-8.8-24.7-13.2-37c-4.7-13.2-9.4-26.4-14.1-39.5c-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.9-0.6-2.9c-0.6-3.8,2.4-6.8,6.1-6c1.5,0.3,3,1.1,4.3,2
    c4,2.7,5.8,2.7,9.9,0c1.2-0.8,2.8-1.1,4.1-1.8c3.2-1.5,6.4-3.1,9.5-4.7c0.5-0.3,1-0.8,1.5-1c7.8-3.6,15.6-7.1,23.4-10.6
    c4.5-2,4.3-1.9,5.7,2.8c2,6.4,4.4,12.5,8.1,18.3c8.2,12.9,18.2,24.4,27.5,36.5c4.7,6.2,7.8,13.1,10.4,20.4c0.3,0.9,0.8,1.7,1.6,3.4
    c1.3-2.8,2.5-4.8,3.2-7c2.5-7.3,6.3-13.7,11.2-19.6c7.3-8.9,14.5-17.9,21.2-27.2c5.8-8.2,10.8-17,12.8-27.1c0.3-1.7,1-2.4,3.1-1.3
    c5.4,2.8,11.2,4.9,16.7,7.5c3.6,1.7,6.9,3.7,10.4,5.5c2.7,1.4,5.4,2.6,8.1,3.9c2.8,1.2,5.6,2.3,8.3,3.6c2.2,1,3.9,0.7,5.7-0.8
    c1.3-1,2.8-2,4.3-2.5c4.1-1.4,7.6,1.5,7.2,5.9c-0.1,1.3-0.4,2.7-0.9,3.9c-5.7,15.2-11.5,30.3-17.2,45.5c-4.7,12.5-9,25.2-14.2,37.5
    c-3.2,7.5-3.6,15.2-4.6,22.9c-1.9,14.2-3.6,28.5-5.2,42.8c-1.5,13.1-3,26.3-4.4,39.4c-0.2,1.5,0.2,3,0.6,4.5
    c2.7,9.8,5.6,19.5,8.2,29.4c2.6,9.9,4.8,19.9,7.4,29.9c2.5,9.7,5.3,19.3,8.2,28.8c0.3,1.1,1.6,2.1,2.7,2.6c3,1.4,6.2,2.3,9.2,3.7
    c4,1.8,7.7,4,11.7,5.7c6.2,2.6,12.6,5,18.9,7.4c7.2,2.7,14.3,5.3,21.6,7.7c1.5,0.5,3.4,0.2,5,0.7c4,1.1,8,2.1,11.9,3.6
    c3.5,1.3,7.5,1.4,10.5,4.1c0.3,0.3,0.8,0.3,1.2,0.4c4.2,0.7,4.8,1.7,3.4,5.8c-4,11.3-11.6,19-23,22.9c-2.1,0.7-3.3,1.8-3.6,4.1
    c-1,6.2-4,11.7-7.4,16.8c-3.9,5.7-10,8.8-16.8,10.2c-3.8,0.8-7.6,1.5-11.4,2.6c-1.1,0.3-2.3,1.4-3,2.4c-3.6,5.1-7.2,10.3-13.3,12.7
    c-5,2-10.3,2.4-15.5,2c-2.1-0.2-3.4,0.4-4.9,1.9c-7.6,7.6-17,10-26.7,6.3c-4-1.5-6.2-0.8-9,1.2c-3,2.2-6,4.4-8.9,6.6
    c-0.7,0.5-1.2,1.3-1.8,2c-0.9,1-1.7,2-2.6,3c-0.8-1.1-1.6-2.1-2.3-3.2c-1.3-1.9-2.1-4.9-3.8-5.5c-1.6-0.5-4.2,1.3-6.2,2.3
    c-5.2,2.5-10.6,4.7-15.6,7.6c-3.2,1.8-5.9,4.6-8.5,7.2c-1.5,1.5-2.4,2-3.7,0.1c-3.2-4.4-7.6-7.1-12.6-9.2
    c-5.1-2.2-10.1-4.8-15.1-7.4c-2.2-1.1-3.6-0.9-4.7,1.5c-0.8,1.9-1.9,3.6-3,5.4c-0.8,1.4-1.9,1.9-2.8,0.2c-2-4.2-5.6-6.6-9.2-9
    c-2.1-1.4-4.1-2.8-6.3-3.9c-0.7-0.4-2-0.4-2.7,0c-5.9,3.6-16.9,3.5-22.4-0.3c-2.8-1.9-5.4-4.1-8.2-5.9c-0.9-0.6-2.1-0.8-3.2-0.7
    c-5.4,0.2-10.7-0.1-15.8-2c-6-2.2-9.7-7.1-13-12.3c-1.4-2.2-3.1-2.8-5.4-3.3c-5.3-1.2-10.6-2.2-15.6-4.1
    c-8.4-3.1-12.6-10.4-15.9-18.2c-1-2.3-1.7-4.9-2.2-7.4c-0.4-1.9-1.4-2.8-3-3.3c-8.7-2.7-15.1-8.3-20.2-15.8c-2.1-3.1-3-6.3-3.7-9.7
    c-0.2-0.9,0.8-2.6,1.6-3.1c2.3-1.2,4.8-2.1,7.2-2.9c2.3-0.8,4.6-1.4,6.9-2c5.4-1.3,10.8-2.4,16.2-3.9c5.7-1.6,11.4-3.6,16.9-5.3
    C74.3,361,74.1,360.1,73.9,359.4L73.9,359.4z"/>

<path class="sleeve-left" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M326.1,62.6c0.4,2.1,0.8,4.2,1,6.3c0.8,9.2,1.6,18.5,2.4,27.8c1.1,14.3,2,28.7,3.2,43
    c1.2,15.8,2.6,31.5,4,47.2c1.1,11.6,2.3,23.3,3.5,34.9c1,9.3,2.1,18.6,3.2,27.9c0.1,0.5,0.3,1.1,0.2,1.6c-0.8,6.2,1.5,12,1.9,18.1
    c0.4,5.8,1.5,11.6,2.4,17.3c0.7,4.6,1.7,9.1,2.5,13.6c0.3,1.5,0.3,3,0.4,4.5c0,0.4-0.1,1,0,1.3c2.8,5.2,2.7,11.1,4,16.6
    c0.3,1.4,1,2.7,1.3,4.1c0.5,2.3,0.8,4.6,1.2,6.9c0.8,4,1.5,7.9,2.4,11.8c1.1,4.7,2.1,9.3,1.2,14.1c-0.5,3-2.4,3.2-5.8,1.8
    c-6-2.6-12.1-5-18.3-7.3c-4.3-1.6-9.2-2.3-12.9-4.8c-5.5-3.7-11.7-5.7-17.5-8.7c-1.1-0.5-1.9-2.1-2.3-3.3
    c-3.4-11.4-6.7-22.7-9.8-34.2c-2.3-8.4-4.3-16.9-6.6-25.4c-2.3-8.6-4.7-17.2-7-25.8c-0.5-2-0.7-4.3-0.5-6.3c1.5-14.5,3-29,4.8-43.4
    c2.1-16.5,4.2-32.9,6.9-49.3c0.9-5.7,3.3-11.2,5.3-16.7c6.7-18.3,13.6-36.6,20.5-54.8c2.2-5.8,4.4-11.6,6.7-17.5
    c0.2-0.5,0.5-0.9,0.7-1.3C325.6,62.6,325.8,62.6,326.1,62.6z"/>

<path class="sleeve-right" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M74,359.3c-1.9,0.6-3.8,1.3-5.7,1.9c-1.2,0.4-2.3,0.7-3.4,1c0-4.2,0.1-8,0-11.9c-0.1-3.8,0.7-7.4,1.8-11
    c1.2-4.2,1.7-8.5,2.5-12.8c1.3-7.5,2.5-15,3.9-22.5c1.3-7.1,3.1-14.2,4.1-21.4c1.5-10.4,3.3-20.7,4-31.2
    c0.9-13.3,2.9-26.4,4.3-39.6c1.4-13.3,2.7-26.6,3.8-40c1.8-21.2,3.3-42.4,5-63.6c1.2-14.5,2.5-29,3.7-43.5c0.1-1.4,0.5-2.7,0.8-4.1
    c0.2,0,0.5-0.1,0.7-0.1c0.3,0.7,0.7,1.3,0.9,2c6.9,19,13.7,38.1,20.5,57.1c3.6,10.2,7.5,20.4,10.5,30.8c1.8,6,2.1,12.4,3,18.7
    c1.4,10.1,2.9,20.1,4.2,30.2c1.3,9.8,2.4,19.7,3.5,29.5c0.7,5.7,1.4,11.3,1.8,17c0.2,2.3-0.1,4.8-0.7,7.1
    c-1.5,6.1-3.3,12.2-4.9,18.3c-3.1,12-6,24-9.2,36c-2.5,9.6-5.3,19.1-7.7,28.7c-0.7,2.6-2,4.2-4.5,5.1c-3.1,1.2-6.1,2.4-9.1,3.9
    c-1.4,0.7-2.5,1.9-3.7,2.8c-0.4,0.3-0.9,0.5-1.3,0.6c-1.9,0.6-3.8,1.2-5.6,1.9c-6,2.2-12,4.4-18.1,6.7
    C77.4,357.8,75.7,358.6,74,359.3C73.9,359.4,74,359.3,74,359.3z"/>

<path class="upper-neckline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10"  d="M212.8,64.3c0.4-1,1-2.1,1.3-3.1c3.1-9.9,8.3-18.7,14.3-27.1c3.8-5.2,7.7-10.4,11.9-15.4
    c1.5-1.8,3.8-2.9,5.9-4.1c0.3-0.2,1.7,0.7,2,1.3c1,2.6,1.7,5.3,2.4,7.9c0.2,0.9,0.2,2.3-0.3,3c-3.4,5-6.9,10-10.5,14.9
    c-6.2,8.5-12.6,16.8-18.9,25.2c-2.4,3.2-4.5,6.6-6.8,9.9c-1.5,2.1-2.2,2.1-3.8,0c-5.3-7.4-10.4-14.9-15.8-22.2
    c-5.2-7-10.6-13.9-15.9-20.8c-1.7-2.2-3.2-4.5-4.5-6.9c-0.5-0.9-0.4-2.3-0.2-3.3c0.6-2.6,1.5-5.1,2.2-7.7c0.5-1.9,1.4-1.7,2.7-0.8
    c6.8,4.5,11.7,10.9,16,17.6c1.6,2.5,3.3,4.9,4.9,7.3c4.5,6.6,7.9,13.7,10.5,21.3c0.4,1.1,1,2.1,1.6,3.2
    C212.2,64.4,212.5,64.3,212.8,64.3z"/>

<path class="lower-neckline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M212.5,110.1c-0.8-1.3-1.5-2-1.8-2.9c-2.6-7.9-7.1-14.7-12.3-21.1c-6.8-8.4-13.6-16.8-19.9-25.5
    c-5.3-7.4-9.8-15.3-12.3-24.2c-0.2-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.5-1.8c-0.8-3.8,1.7-6.9,5.6-6.5c1,0.1,2.1,1.3,2.7,2.2c5.5,7.5,10.9,15,16.3,22.5
    c6.2,8.6,12.4,17.2,18.7,25.8c2.5,3.5,3.7,3.5,6.2,0c5.2-7.2,10.1-14.6,15.4-21.8c5.4-7.3,11-14.5,16.5-21.7
    c1.3-1.8,2.4-3.7,3.6-5.6c0.9-1.5,2.1-1.7,3.7-1c0.9,0.4,2,0.6,2.6,1.2c0.9,0.9,1.8,2.2,1.8,3.4c0,1.6-0.6,3.3-1.2,4.9
    c-2.1,5.7-4.1,11.4-7.9,16.3c-6.7,8.9-13.3,17.8-19.9,26.8c-4.2,5.7-8.4,11.5-12.3,17.5c-1.7,2.7-2.7,5.8-4,8.8
    C213.5,107.9,213.1,108.7,212.5,110.1z"/>

    </svg>

    $('input#body_color').change(function () {
var colored = $(this).val();
$('.main-body').css({ fill: colored });
```

});

```
    $('input#sleeve_color').change(function () {
var colored = $(this).val();
$('.sleeve-right').css({ fill: colored });
```

});

```
    $('input#sleeve_color').change(function () {
var colored = $(this).val();
$('.sleeve-left').css({ fill: colored });
```

});

```
    $('input#lneck_color').change(function () {
var colored = $(this).val();
$('.lower-neckline').css({ fill: colored });
```

});

```
    $('input#uneck_color').change(function () {
var colored = $(this).val();
$('.upper-neckline').css({ fill: colored });
```

});

```
        $('.draggable').draggable({ helper: "clone" });
$('.draggable').bind('dragstop', function (event, ui) {
$(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());
});
```

Comment: Updated my response and added some more comments. See if that is helpful